# Find the power of the quotient set of this relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In the set $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ of all infinite sequences with integers words we define the relation of equivalence: $f\equiv g \Leftrightarrow((f(2n)=g(2n))  \wedge(f(n)\cdot g(n)>0 \vee f(n)=0=g(n)))$ for $f,g \in \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$. 
> Find the power of the quotient set of this relation.

**My try:**
Let $|A|$ - the power of the quotient set of this relation. I know that $A \subseteq Z^{\mathbb N} \Rightarrow |A| \le |\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}|=continuum$. If I show $|A| \ge continuum$, from Schröder–Bernstein theorem  I will know that $|A|=continuum$. I can find a function $X \rightarrow A$ which is $1-1$ and $|X|=continuum$ to show that $|A| \ge continuum$ but it is difficult for me and I have other idea but I don't know if this is correct:
 
Let $B=\left\{f: \mathbb N  \rightarrow \left\{ -1,1\right\}: f(2n)=g(2n) \right\}$. $B\subseteq A$ so $|A|\ge|B|=continuum$
Can you check the correctness of my idea?

Comment: I don't really understand the definition of $B$. Do you take specific $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @Mark I did not define specific $ f $ and $ g $ at all, I used only the assumptions when $ f $ is in relation to $ g $

Comment: Can you describe the set $B$ then? Because it doesn't look very clear right now.

Comment: @Mark I wanted to $B\subseteq A$ because then I can say that $|A|\ge|B|=continuum$. $A$ is from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$ so in $B$ I done $\mathbb N  \rightarrow \left\{ -1,1\right\}$. Moreover I took one condition from the quotient $ A $. This time I guess it's incorrect, but I can not do it differently

Comment: What is the $g$ occurring in your definition of $B$? Unlike $f$, it is not a dummy variable, but it is also no defined in any way. A similar comment is true about $n$, which is also not defined, However, for $n$ I assume that there is an implicit assumption of "for all $n$" being applied. Buf for the $g$ in the definition of $B$, that makes no sense, as such a "for all" would mean that $B$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map that carries $f$ to the equivalence class of $h_f$, where $$h_f(n) = \begin{cases} f\left(\frac n2\right) & n\text{ even}\\f\left(\frac {n+1}2\right) & n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
Can you see why this map is injective?

But you also have another error in your logic: $A \not \subseteq \Bbb Z^\Bbb N$. It is in fact a set of subsets of $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$.

However, this is not hard to correct, as there is a surjection from $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$ onto $A$.